# simple_form missing translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a `date` attribute of `Date` type.

```
= f.input :date
```

And `simple_form` raises an exception:

```
undefined method `map' for "translation missing: fr.date.order":String
```

I am not supposed to do anything by default. Translations should be okay. I have no clue what I should look for.

The full code view:

```
section
  .row
    h1= t('actions.new')

  .row
    = simple_form_for @group_action, url: admin_actions_path do |f|
      = f.input :concerned_object
      = f.input :concerned_company
      = f.input :date
      = f.input :amount_estimation
      = f.input :description
      = f.input :tags

      = f.button :submit
```

The `group_action` schema:

```
  create_table "group_actions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                        null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "concerned_object",  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "concerned_company", default: "", null: false
    t.date     "date",                           null: false
    t.string   "amount_estimation", default: "", null: false
    t.text     "description",       default: "", null: false
    t.string   "tags"
  end
```

The model:

```
class GroupAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lawyer, class_name: User, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```

---

A colleague proposed me to use `order` option as a workaround:

```
= f.input :date, order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

This gets rid of the exception but I'm still having trouble with default translations. On the image below, it's the select element where are supposed to be listed the months.

[image]

Comment: can you post your complete error message and some more code to elaborate

Comment: I'm okay to post more code but I have no idea what to put as I don't know what else could be implied…

Comment: @AdrienGiboire  please post your entire form and model code

Comment: I've added schema, view and related model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use a different locale than `:en`, you have to install `rails-i18n` gem.

Answer (score -1):

1) 
Also, `js.coffee` should be used, since using `js.coffee.haml` cause conflicts with haml and coffee.

So the answer is "no, it doesn't seem like you can use `js.coffee.haml` just use `js.coffee.erb` which is actually enabled by the extension `js.coffee`, which implicitly appends `.erb` at the end of it.

2)
I was using simple form, and my form should have looked like this instead

```
= simple_form_for @entry, remote: true do |f|
  = f.input :body
  = f.button :submit, :disable_with => "Submitting…"
```